# Reading the contents at three URLs using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm learning [promises](/questions/tagged/promises) and now I'm trying to figure out if something in this code can be improved. This code is expected 3 urls and then async parallel calls should be done. When all requests are finished thet just show each request's data.

```
const hyperquest = require('hyperquest');
const BufferList = require('bl');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var tasks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    new function(index) {
        tasks[index] = new Promise(function(resolve) {
            makeRequest(resolve, index);
        });
    }(i);
}

Promise.all(tasks).then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.bl.toString());
    })
});

function makeRequest(resolve, step) {
    var bl = new BufferList();
    var req = hyperquest(process.argv[step + 2]);
    req.on('end', function() {
        resolve({data: bl});
    });
    req.pipe(bl);
}
```

The main question is it right usage of Promise.
Should I use this

> ```
> tasks[index] = new Promise(function(resolve) { makeRequest(resolve, index); });
> ```

or it can be simplified?

Also `req.on('end', function() { resolve({data: bl}); });` is a direct call of resolver callback but maybe it's possible without it?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: Read 3 urls and then print their content using Promises :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the whole it does not look very elegant, especially `new function`, building functions in a loop and building the Promise array.

I would suggest you invest time in the bluebird [`Promise.map`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#mapfunction-mapper--object-options---promise) function and write something like this:

```
var indexes = [0,1,2];
Promise.map(indexes, function(index) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        makeRequest(resolve, index);
    });
}).then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.bl.toString());
    })
});
```

Other than that, you seem very light on the failure handling, make sure to use `catch` and `reject`.